# Python Select PDF File Parts and Merge into One

Tags: python, file, merge, pypdf

I've many PDF Files in One Folder. Two of files have same name end with _01 and _03 these number could be random. I want to merge these two files having same name into one PDF with the name the parts have. any Idea? 
Like story-writing_01.pdf, story-writing_02.pdf, game-changer_01.pdf, game-changer_09.pdf

Comment: So, you want to merge pdf who have same name but different numeral in the end. Right?.

Comment: Thanks Rahaul, I've done myself.

Comment: Then you could answer the question yourself.  This might help people with the same or a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created List of files path and append them in dictionary with condition. if key is not in value then add in dictionary.
which make exact pairs of two consective parts. which then i merged into pdf.